# Fastest way to compute sum of a submatrix

Tags: matlab

What's the fastest way of computing the sum of a submatrix? Currently I'm going about this in the following way:

```
x = [1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4]

>> y = x(1:2, 1:2);
>> y

y =

     1     2
     1     2

>> sum(y(:))

ans =

     6

>>
```

How can I compute the sum of all submatrices of `x`?

**Edit**

At each point (x,y) in the matrix, I want to compute the sum for a window of size 2M+1. For example, if I have a 4x4 matrix I want to compute the sums for 3x3 windows at each point where this is possible (e.g. it wouldn't be possible for the edges because the window would spill off the matrix)

```
for i = M:ncols-M
    for j=M:nrows-M

    end
end
```

**Example**
For a 4x4 matrix with a window size of 3, I would want these sums:

sum centered at (2,2)

```
+ + + x
+ + + x
+ + + x
x x x x
```

sum centered at (3,2)

```
x + + +
x + + +
x + + +
x x x x
```

sum centered at (2,3)

```
x x x x
+ + + x
+ + + x
+ + + x
```

sum centered at (3,3)

```
x x x x
x + + +
x + + +
x + + +
```

Comment: But @Adriaan where's the `bsxfun` in that?

Comment: What is your definition of a submatrix?

Comment: So are you going to clear things up? You have four answers that are interpreting your question differently. Please stop this madness and answer our inquiry.

Comment: What sum is expected at (1,1) and (1,2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was created before clarifications by the OP. It assumes the **submatrices do not overlap**!

---

If you have the **Image Processing Toolbox** you can use [**`blockproc`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
A = blockproc(x,[2 2],@(k) sum(k.data(:)))
```

If you don't have it you can use [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
n = 2;              %// number of elements per block in row direction
N = size(x,1)/n;    %// number of blocks in row direction
m = 2;              %// number of elements per block in column direction
M = size(x,2)/m;    %// number of blocks in column direction

idx = repelem( reshape(1:(N*M),N,M),n,m)
B = reshape( accumarray(x(:),idx(:)), N, M )
```

Some heavy reshaping will work too:

```
C = reshape(sum(reshape(permute(sum(reshape(x,n,m,[])),[2,3,1]).',n,[])),n,[]).'
```

---

```
A = B = C =

     6    14
     6    14
```

Comment: @Apollo If you accept my answer, it is even less clear what you want. My answer doesn't compute what you want, after your edit. Luis Mendo's does.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at computing a [summed area table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table).  Simply put, each element at row `i` and column `j` - `(i,j)` - in the output is the sum of the submatrix bounded from the top-left corner to the point of interest `(i,j)` which serves as the bottom right corner.

It's very simple with [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html):

```
y = cumsum(cumsum(x, 1), 2);
```

Example:

```
>> x = repmat(1:4, 4, 1); %// your example
>> x

x =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
```

... and the output:

```
>> y = cumsum(cumsum(x, 1), 2)

y =

     1     3     6    10
     2     6    12    20
     3     9    18    30
     4    12    24    40
```

As such, for your example, the submatrix sum from the top left corner to `(i,j) = (2,2)` is equal to 6.

Comment: What is this magic! I interpreted this as: there's four `2x2` matrices in his matrix, and of each of the four he wants the sum.

Comment: @Adriaan yeah on second thought I've misinterpreted the question.  Going to wait for clarification before I correct.

Comment: Based on the matrix `y`, arbitrary submatrices can be summed up in constant time. To get `h=x(a(1):a(2),a(3):a(4));h=sum(h(:));` use `h=y(a(2),a(4))-y(a(1)-1,a(4))-y(a(2),a(3)-1)+y(a(1)-1,a(3)-1)`

Comment: @Daniel that's the beauty of summed area tables!

Comment: @rayryeng Does the summed area table work for my example above? How would I get the sums of those matrices?

Comment: @Apollo I'll make an edit soon but Luis Mendoza answer is what you're looking for if you don't want to wait.

Answer (score 3):

If by "submatrix" you mean a **sliding** 2D-window of fixed size, that's essentially a 2D-convolution:

```
x = [1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4];
m = 2; n = 2; %// submatrix size
result = conv2(x, ones(m, n), 'valid');
```

In this example,

```
result =
     6    10    14
     6    10    14
     6    10    14
```

Comment: Appears, that your Mentalist skills have been the best after all, again. ;)

Comment: Hahaha. That, or it was the only answer that you guys had left :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = repmat(1:4, 4, 1); %// your example
[A,B] = size(x);
kk=1;
for ii = 1:2:A
    for jj = 1:2:B
        subsummed(kk) = sum(sum(x(ii:ii+1,jj:jj+1)));
        kk = kk+1;
    end
end
```

My looped version, in case you mean a "submatrix" in case of the four `2x2` matrices that make up your full one.